# Schur decomposition and upper triangular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition, schur-decomposition

Can someone please help me with this problem.
If $A\in \mathbb C^{n\times n}$ has distinct eigenvalues. How do I show that if $Q^*AQ=T$ is the Shur decomposition and $AB=BA$, then $Q^*BQ$ is upper triangular?

Comment: This is plainly not true.   **However**, it is true that if $AB = BA$, then there exists a (unitary) $Q$ such that both $Q^*AQ$ and $Q^*BQ$ are upper triangular

Comment: @Omnomnomnom its already stated that $A$ commutes with $B$

Comment: Right, so there exists a (unitary) matrix $Q$ such that $Q^*AQ$ and $Q^*BQ$ are upper triangular.  It is **not** true that $Q^*AQ$ is upper triangular implies that $Q^*BQ$ is upper triangular.

Answer (score 2):

The crucial argument is  as follows.

Consider any eigenvector $\lambda$ of $A$ and associated eigenvector $v$. Then $$A(Bv)=(AB)v=(BA)v=B(Av)=B(\lambda v)=\lambda(Bv)$$

Therefore $Bv$ is also an eigenvector of $A$ associated with $\lambda$ and so $Bv$ is a scalar multiple of $v$. Thus  $v$ is also an eigenvector of $B$.

If a basis is used with $v$ as its first element, the linear transformations represented by $A$ and $B$ will therefore have all first row entries zero apart (possibly) from the first entry which  will be the respective eigenvalues.

An inductive argument can then be used to complete the proof.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I used induction but by establishing $TX=XT$  first where $X$ is $Q^*BQ$